# Jasmine testing, seemingly unrelated tests are interfering with other tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

Please look for the // **** THIS IS THE CODE IN QUESTION, BELOW this line **** comment.

There are two main describe functions in the code I sectioned off with comments. In the first describe("Start up defaults") if I take out the last test it('gameStarted and gameOver should be false'), all the tests in the second describe("player presses start") PASS (Im referring to the tests testing whether elements have the class 'greyed').

But if I include that last test as it is now, then all those tests in the second describe("player presses start") on whether the element has the class 'greyed' FAIL.

If I comment out that last test it('gameStarted and gameOver should be false'), then the other tests pass again. With it commented out, if I copy and paste the test above it it('player 2 should be Computer') (to ensure it wasnt a syntax problem), the other tests fail again! I am at my wits end. Its like there's a limit to how many it()'s I can put in that describe block.

To reiterate, the spyClickEvent tests always pass.
The start button starts the game and greys out all the options except for the restart button.

The entire project is on Github here: https://github.com/Spekachu/Tic-Tac-Toe

You can see the Javascript on codepen http://codepen.io/Spekachu/pen/adKprJ?editors=0010
but with no Jasmine there.
The booleans are all initialized to what I expect them to be in these tests.

Some javascript code is posted at the bottom, like the start function when the start button is pressed.

```
describe('Tic Tac Toe', function(){
  jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = '/';
  var spyClickEvent; // will detect all button clicks and game board clicks
  beforeEach(function(){
    loadFixtures('index.html');
  });
  describe("Game Board", function(){
    it ('should have id "game-board"', function(){
      expect( $('#game-board') ).toExist();
    });
    describe ('children', function(){
      it ('there should be 5 children', function(){
        expect( $('#game-board').children().length ).toEqual(5);
      });
      describe ('#name-plate', function(){
        it ('exists', function(){
          expect( $('#name-plate') ).toExist();
        });
      });
      describe ('#result-ribbon', function(){
        it ('exists', function(){
          expect( $('#result-ribbon') ).toExist();
        });
      });
      describe ('#play-wrapper', function(){
        it ('exists', function(){
          expect( $('#play-wrapper') ).toExist();
        });
        describe ('has #play-area, where the pieces get played', function(){
          it("exists", function(){
            expect( $('#play-area') ).toExist();
          });
          describe('slots', function(){
            it('should have 9 slots', function(){
              $('#play-area').html('');
              initVars();
              expect($('#play-area').children().length).toEqual(9);
            });
            it('each slot has an X and O background inset', function(){
              $('#play-area').children().each(function(slot, val){
                expect(val).toContainElement('p.shadow.o'); expect(val).toContainElement('p.shadow.x');
              });
            });
            it('should have no played pieces at start', function(){
              expect(gamePrintOut).toEqual(" | | \n | | \n | | ");
              expect(playedPieces.length).toEqual(0);
              expect(availSlots.length).toEqual(9);
            });
            // GAME PLAY
          });
        });
      });
      describe ('#options-wrapper', function(){
        it ('exists', function(){
          expect( $('#options-wrapper') ).toExist();
        });

 // *******************************************************************
 // !!!!!! THIS IS THE CODE IN QUESTION, BELOW this line !!!!!!!!!!!!!!

        describe('Start up defaults', function(){
          it('Restart should be greyed out while the rest are red and clickable', function(){
            expect($('#restart')).toHaveClass('greyed');
            expect($('#start')).not.toHaveClass('greyed');
            expect($('.piece-switch')).not.toHaveClass('greyed');
            expect($('.choice-switch')).not.toHaveClass('greyed');
            expect($('.order-switch')).not.toHaveClass('greyed');
          });
          it('player should be x, and be going first', function(){
            expect(userIsX).toBe(true);
            expect(userFirst).toBe(true);
            expect(usersTurn).toBe(true);
          });
          it('player 2 should be Computer', function(){
            expect(player2IsComp).toBe(true);
          });
          it('player 2 should be Computer', function(){
            expect(player2IsComp).toBe(true);
          });
          it('gameStarted and gameOver should be false', function(){
            expect(gameStarted).toBe(false);
            expect(gameOver).toBe(false);
          });
        });

        describe ('Player presses start', function(){
          it ('should grey out options and itself and make Restart red and clickable', function(){
            spyClickEvent = spyOnEvent('#start', 'click');
            $('#start').trigger( "click" );
            expect('click').toHaveBeenTriggeredOn('#start');
            expect(spyClickEvent).toHaveBeenTriggered();

            expect($('#restart')).not.toHaveClass('greyed');
            expect($('#start')).toHaveClass('greyed');
            expect($('.piece-switch')).toHaveClass('greyed');
            expect($('.choice-switch')).toHaveClass('greyed');
            expect($('.order-switch')).toHaveClass('greyed');
          });
        });

 // ^^^^^^^^ THIS IS THE CODE IN QUESTION, ABOVE this line ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 // *******************************************************************

      });
      describe ('#made-by', function(){
        it ('exists', function(){
          expect( $('#made-by') ).toExist();
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

SELECT JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
var usersTurn = true;
var userFirst = true;
var gameStarted = false;
var gameOver = false;
var userIsX = true;
var p2CanWin = false;
var userCanWin = false;
var player2IsComp = true;

var xSymbol = '&#x02A2F';
var isAndroid = /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
if (isAndroid) {
  xSymbol = 'x';
}
var slots = ('<div class="slot"> <p class="shadow x">'+ xSymbol +'</p> <p class="shadow o">O</p> </div> ').repeat(9);

function initVars() {
  playArea.html(slots);
  winningSlots = [];
  printGame();
}
function startGame() {
  $('#restart').removeClass('greyed');
  $('#start').addClass('greyed');
  $('.switch-container .switch').addClass('greyed');
  gameStarted = true;
  gameOver = false;
  if (!userFirst)
    computerGo();
  updateSizes();
}
```

UPDATE

if I leave that last test it('gameStarted and gameOver should be false'){...}); commented out so everything passes --> 
Then if I insert this code within the same describe("player presses start"), and after the it("should grey out options..."){...}

```
      it ("this should pass", function(){
        expect(1).toEqual(1);
      });
```

Everything still passes. But if I cut and paste it BEFORE the it("should grey out all other options..."), then they fail again!

(Also I know I should have started this project with testing first, unfortunately I started after)

Comment: Can you post the code for these variables/methods: `gameStarted`, `userIsX`, `initVars()`, etc?

Comment: Yes! I added the codepen link that has all the js. gameStarted and the other booleans are intialized in my .js to what I expect them to be in these tests. initVars() simply adds the html for 9 divs for the gameboard. All other variables are initialized when declared.

Comment: if I call the startGame() function after the spyClickEvents and before the failing tests, they all pass and I have no problems. I was assuming that the .trigger function would trigger my .js calling the startGame() function, but perhaps the code is going past triggering the "click". Its still a mystery to me why adding ANYmore it() functions ABOVE the it('should grey out options'){...} causes those tests to fail.

Comment: Take the error messages of Jasmine with a grain of salt. Sometimes it reports an error somewhere completely different then where you actually made the mistake.

Comment: Yeah, even though I can move on now, I dont understand what was the error. Anyway, thanks for your help. I guess I'm still getting used to Jasmine, it is my first time with it afterall.

Answer (score -2):

So, I checked out your code and the console log messages seem to me that the test is run before jquery can initialize. I'm not sure why, because I've not worked with jquery-jasmine before, but making your [test async](http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support) should fix that problem:

```
describe ('Player presses start', function(){
    it ('should grey out options and itself and make Restart red and clickable', function(done){
        setTimeout(function() {
            spyClickEvent = spyOnEvent('#start', 'click');
            $('#start').trigger( "click" );
            expect('click').toHaveBeenTriggeredOn('#start');
            expect(spyClickEvent).toHaveBeenTriggered();
            expect($('#restart')).not.toHaveClass('greyed');
            expect($('#start')).toHaveClass('greyed');
            expect($('.piece-switch')).toHaveClass('greyed');
            expect($('.piece-switch')).toHaveClass('greyed');
            expect($('.choice-switch')).toHaveClass('greyed');
            expect($('.order-switch')).toHaveClass('greyed');
            done();
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Using timeouts to wait for something to happen is very rarely a good solution. This isn't one of the rare cases.

Comment: Better delete that test. No one is going to wait 2s for it.